# .net core 2.2 Web Api not returning any messages, Status code returned fine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I am setting up a new .net core webapi using v2.2.
This has a simple get function which is supposed to return either the current date if the request is a heartbeat or a Json object.

I have set up the heartbeat function as a HTTPGet using an IActionResult return type.
I have tried using both the Controllerbase class as well as the Controller class but am having the same issue no matter which I try

My controller class declaration is as follows:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    IConfiguration _iconfiguration;


    public TestController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _iconfiguration = configuration;
    }

    // GET: api/Interceptor        
    [HttpGet("Heartbeat")]        
    public IActionResult Get()
    {


        //Set the return DateTime for return value
        string currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");            

        return Ok(currentDateTime);
    //return Ok("Heartbeat Message Received");
        //return Ok(new { message = "Heartbeat Message Received: " + currentDateTime });            
        //var result = new OkObjectResult(new { message = "200 OK", currentDate = DateTime.Now });
        //return result;
       //return Ok(Json("123"));            
        //return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried various methods to try and get a return string to be delivered back.
When I do the call in Postman to this service, I get the 200Ok return status fine, however the body of my response (in this case the current date time) just comes back empty.
return types tried:

- Ok(result)
- Ok(string)
- OkResultObject(object)
- string
- array

In all cases Postman returns me a status 200 Ok but no body.

[Screenshot of what I see when I do a postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEaN0.jpg)

The IDE I am using is VS2017 Enterprise version 15.9.7

Comment: If you paste url for your GET request in browser, do you see body?

Comment: @KrishnaDhugana No my Get request in a browser is also giving me the same result

Comment: Isn't `IActionResult` all gone with the old MVC 5.2 and you should just return objects now?

Comment: How can you be sure that it is not returning the value in the body but only the 200 success code? Can you post a screen shot.

Comment: @Thangadurai I have attached a screenshot of the result I get while doing a Postman call. As you will see it returns the HTTP Status code but not the result I want to pass back

Comment: Can you check the 'Raw' response.

Comment: @Thangadurai Raw is also empty

Comment: @rbharany1 You would need to include the `ProducesResponseType` property on your `IActionResult`. Add this: `[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(string))] `. If you choose to use `ActionResult`, then you can exclude the `Type` property.

Comment: May be you are hitting a different action method not the one, that you have mentioned. There is no way that the framework can decide, "OK...i will return only the OK (HTTP 200) but not the data"

Comment: I could get the body successfully by using your code.Your postman screenshot shows the url like `/V1/Interceptor/Heartbeat`. But you did not define the route attribute in your controller. I suggest that you could set breakpoint to your action and debug whether it gets into the right action.

Comment: Could you share more details about your code which could reproduce your issue?

Comment: @rbharany1 Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use this attribute on your controller class

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyCustomController : ControllerBase
```

You can read more on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks but I have tried both Controller and ControllerBase. Both give me the same issue of Status code returned but no body. I have also tried the above link but saw nothing there which helps me

Answer (score 1):

You need use the attributes on your class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

I created a new project for test this, i started on debug mode and called my address:

http://localhost:my_port/api/Test

The address my API is Test, but my class called TestController.

My class is very simple:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

}

And returns: ["value1","value2"]

Try this.

Comment: My Route and API Controller attraibutes are already set. Thank you for this example but it is for the default controller set up by the VS IDE. This works fine for me as well. However when I change the IEnumerable to IActionResult is when I am getting the issue

Answer (score 1):

The route for this action is `/Heartbeat`, because that's what you've set it to. Not sure what `/V1/Interceptor/Heartbeat` is hitting, but it's not this action. If that's the route you want for this action then you need to add the following attribute to your controller:

```
`[Route("V1/Interceptor")]`
```

However, given that you're not getting a 404 currently, there's something that's already using that, it would seem, so you're likely get a route conflict when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    IConfiguration _iconfiguration;


    public TestController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _iconfiguration = configuration;
    }

    // GET: api/Interceptor        
    [HttpGet("Heartbeat")]        
    public IActionResult Get()
       {
            //Set the return DateTime for return value
            string currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");
            return Ok(new
            {
                data = currentDateTime
            });
        }
}


//By this you will get the body parameter as well as you can return many more properties with this like status_code, message etc..
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but it still doesn't return the currentdate variable

Comment: @rbharany1 its work here, might be you need to correction on routing path.

In my local machine the URL: **https://localhost:44315/api/test/heartbeat** and get the response like **data : "2019-09-18 10:33:06:151"**

so can you please verify URL so that you can get exact output as you required.

Comment: Due to this is .NET core(c# application) i can not able to make it live and share you the exact output. So evantually  i need to make a comment over here so that you can get resolution on your issue.